# OSError: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, datetime, path

I am trying to create a new dictionary.

```
import os
import datetime


parent_dir = "E:\\"
directory = "cali"
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%b-%d_%H:%M:%S")

path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory, now) 

os.makedirs(path)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'E:\\cali\\Dec-25_07:53:44'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is one of the characters that are illegal for naming directories in [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007).

Therefore, you need to replace `:` in `("%b-%d_%H:%M:%S")` with `_` to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot create a folder with `:` in name , instead replace

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%b-%d_%H_%M_%S")
```